# When running a command from terminal, how can I know the full path of the command?

Tags: terminal, command-line

Assuming I'm writing in Terminal: 'ctags', how can I know the full path of the command 'ctags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ type ctags
ctags is /usr/bin/ctags
$ type -p ctags
/usr/bin/ctags
```

The second form is useful for doing things like

```
$ file $(type -p ctags)
$ ls -l $(type -p ctags)
```

and is often aliased to `which`.

---

If you don't want to rely on `bash` functionality and prefer an external command, `/usr/bin/whereis` serves a similar purpose:

> The whereis utility checks the standard binary directories for the specified programs, printing out the paths of any it finds.

Because `whereis` doesn't use `$PATH` but rather the result of `sysctl user.cs_path` it may lead to different results.

Comment: Are you sure it's aliased to `which`?  Also, do you know `whereis`? It's interesting because in my case `whereis ctags` yields different result from `which ctags`.

Comment: Hmm, right, the alias isn't set by default. `type` is an internal bash command, `/usr/bin/whereis` is an external command. But I would expect them to give the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Type the command as a parameter, for e.g. to find location of `tar`

```
ls -l $(which tar)
```

which in my case returns

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  6 Jul 26  2012 /usr/bin/tar -> bsdtar
```